# Visual Studio update SQL table schema after changing Visual Basic model file

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

Let's say I have a file Orders.vb, with this content:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports DbContext

Public Class Order
    Public Property id As Guid
    Public Property storeNumber As Integer
End Class
Public Class OrderDBContext
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property Orders() As DbSet(Of Order)
End Class
```

The table was automatically created in SQL Server.

Then I change it to this:

```
...
    Public Property storeNumber As Integer?
...
```

making the `storeNumber` field nullable.

How do I tell Visual Studio to update the SQL Server table based on the new model update?

Comment: Are you using [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)?

Comment: Yes.  The tables were automatically set up for me the first time I compiled the program and queried a test route.